# struct or class in assembly

Tags: class, assembly, macros, masm

I need something like struct or class in c++

For example I need a class with an array and two attribute (size and len) and some function like append and remove .

How can I implement this in assembly with macros and procedures?

Comment: although `struct or class` are not concept of assembly language!

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/467086/220380

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tasm supports eg.

```
struc String  // note: without 't' at the end
   size   dw 100
   len    dw 10
   data   db 0 dup(100)
ends String
```

[Gnu assembler](http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/scientific4/docs/rhel-as-en-4/struct.html) also has a `.struct` directive.

The syntax for [MASM](http://www.hep.wisc.edu/~pinghc/asm5.html) is:

```
String STRUCT
    size dw 100
    len dw 10
String ENDS
```

Usage again from the same MASM manual:

```
ASSUME eax:PTR String
mov ecx, [eax].size,
mov edx, [eax].len
ASSUME eax:nothing
.. or ..
 mov ecx, (String PTR [eax]).size   // One can 'cast' to struct pointer
```

One can also access a local variable directly

```
mov eax, myStruct.len
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample MASM struct from a HID interface routine that I wrote:

```
SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA struct
    CbSize      DWORD   ?
    ClassGuid   GUID    <>
    Flags       DWORD   ?
    Reserved    ULONG   ?
SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA ends
```

Comment: what is GUID <>?, in MASM I can't use this

Comment: "<>" denotes a struct.  GUID is a struct (defined elsewhere), that I have within my SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATE struct.  It's rare to have to do that.  This is merely a snippet of how a struct can be built.  It's is NOT a complete standalone application that you can use.  :-)  You're going to have to adapt the concept for your own use...

Answer (score 2):

Structure in 8086 MASM

**syntax**

```
struct_name STRUC
var_name type ?
...
struct_name ENDS
```

**Rules**

1)It can't be initialized (If initialized results in garbage values)

2)It should be accessed using "direct addressing mode" (If not result in "immediate addressing mode")

**program to add two numbers**

```
DATA SEGMENT
FOO STRUC
A DB ?
B DB ?       
SUM DW ?
FOO ENDS

DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA
START:MOV AX,DATA
      MOV DS,AX

      XOR AX,AX
      MOV DS:[FOO.A],0FFH  
      MOV DS:[FOO.B],0FFH

      MOV AL,DS:[FOO.A]   ;al=ff
      ADD AL,DS:[FOO.B]   ;al=al+ff
      ADC AH,00H          ;ah=ah+carry_flag(1/0)+00
      MOV DS:[FOO.SUM],AX ;sum=ax
      HLT                 ;stop

CODE ENDS
END START
```