# when i am trying to compile below given assembly code, it is giving the error undefined symbol: AXSAVE

Tags: assembly, x86-16

here is the assembly code for msdos source code, when i try to compile the code it is showing the error "MSDOS.ASM(329) : error A2006: undefined symbol : AXSAVE".Please guide.please guide me where i am wrong. i am unable to understand why it is claiming the variable AXSAVE as undefined symbol even if i have declared it under the structure "STKPTRS".

```
CODE    SEGMENT
CODE    ENDS

CONSTANTS       SEGMENT BYTE
CONSTANTS       ENDS

DATA    SEGMENT WORD
DATA    ENDS

DOSGROUP        GROUP   CODE,CONSTANTS,DATA

SEGBIOS SEGMENT
SEGBIOS ENDS

; BOIS entry point definitions

    IF      IBM
BIOSSEG EQU     60H
    ENDIF
    IF      NOT IBM
BIOSSEG EQU     40H
    ENDIF

; Location of user registers relative user stack pointer

STKPTRS STRUC
AXSAVE  DW  ?  <--MSDOS.ASM(329):error A2006:undefined symbol: AXSAVE
BXSAVE  DW  ?
CXSAVE  DW  ?
DXSAVE  DW  ?
SISAVE  DW  ?
DISAVE  DW  ?
BPSAVE  DW  ?
DSSAVE  DW  ?
ESSAVE  DW  ?
IPSAVE  DW  ?
CSSAVE  DW  ?
FSAVE   DW  ?
STKPTRS ENDS

LEAVE:
    CLI
    MOV     SP,CS:[SPSAVE]
    MOV     SS,CS:[SSSAVE]
    MOV     BP,SP
    MOV     BYTE PTR [BP.AXSAVE],AL

    IF      DSKTEST
    MOV     AX,CS:[NSP]
    MOV     CS:[SPSAVE],AX
    MOV     AX,CS:[NSS]
    MOV     CS:[SSSAVE],AX
    ENDIF

    POP     AX
    POP     BX
    POP     CX
    POP     DX
    POP     SI
    POP     DI
    POP     BP
    POP     DS
    POP     ES
    IRET

DATA    SEGMENT WORD
; Init code overlaps with data area below

    ORG     0
SPSAVE  DW      ?
SSSAVE  DW      ?

IF      DSKTEST
NSS     DW      ?
NSP     DW      ?
    ENDIF

DATA    ENDS
    END
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450894/struct-or-class-in-assembly

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems.

For starters, your code is not inside the code segment. That might or might not confuse the assembler. Also, `FSAVE` is a typo, you probably want `FSSAVE`. It's important because `FSAVE` happens to be an instruction and at least jwasm doesn't like that as a struct field. Also `LEAVE` is an instruction, you might have to change that label as well. Using the struct requires a cast or an `ASSUME` and you are also using the wrong size. This version assembles with jwasm, I don't have masm to test with:

```
IBM=0
DSKTEST=1

CONSTANTS       SEGMENT BYTE
CONSTANTS       ENDS

DATA    SEGMENT WORD
DATA    ENDS

DOSGROUP        GROUP   CODE,CONSTANTS,DATA

SEGBIOS SEGMENT
SEGBIOS ENDS

; BOIS entry point definitions

    IF      IBM
BIOSSEG EQU     60H
    ENDIF
    IF      NOT IBM
BIOSSEG EQU     40H
    ENDIF

; Location of user registers relative user stack pointer

STKPTRS STRUC
AXSAVE  DW  ?
BXSAVE  DW  ?
CXSAVE  DW  ?
DXSAVE  DW  ?
SISAVE  DW  ?
DISAVE  DW  ?
BPSAVE  DW  ?
DSSAVE  DW  ?
ESSAVE  DW  ?
IPSAVE  DW  ?
CSSAVE  DW  ?
FSSAVE  DW  ?
STKPTRS ENDS

CODE    SEGMENT

_LEAVE:
    CLI
    MOV     SP,CS:[SPSAVE]
    MOV     SS,CS:[SSSAVE]
    MOV     BP,SP
    MOV     (STKPTRS PTR [BP]).AXSAVE,AX

    IF      DSKTEST
    MOV     AX,CS:[NSP]
    MOV     CS:[SPSAVE],AX
    MOV     AX,CS:[NSS]
    MOV     CS:[SSSAVE],AX
    ENDIF

    POP     AX
    POP     BX
    POP     CX
    POP     DX
    POP     SI
    POP     DI
    POP     BP
    POP     DS
    POP     ES
    IRET
CODE    ENDS

DATA    SEGMENT WORD
; Init code overlaps with data area below

    ORG     0
SPSAVE  DW      ?
SSSAVE  DW      ?

IF      DSKTEST
NSS     DW      ?
NSP     DW      ?
    ENDIF

DATA    ENDS
    END
```