# How to compare number with STRUCT Field?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I tried to output structs that less than entered value, but it either print all structs or print nothing. I initialize some structs (in my case 3 objects), then enter value from keyboard, convert it to asm number, but when I compare values in procedure from struct with this number I don't get correct answer.

Here is the code:

```
.686
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc
include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc
include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includeLib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib

Good STRUCT
    Abbr       BYTE 20 DUP(?)
    Descr BYTE 20 DUP(?)
    Price       DWORD ?
    Count       DWORD ?
Good ENDS

PrintGoods PROTO ptrGood:PTR Good

.data
    sConsTitle BYTE "Lab rab 5", 0
    strTask BYTE "Output list of goods that lower then entered price", 0Dh, 0Ah, 0Ah, 0h
    sPrompt BYTE "Enter price", 0Dh, 0Ah, 0h

    clrt BYTE 0Ah, 0Dh, 0
    comma BYTE ", ", 0
    buffer BYTE 20 DUP(0)


    good_1 Good <"q", "g", 1600, 13>
    good_2 Good <"w", "m", 800, 24>
    good_3 Good <"e", "s", 250, 24>
.data?
    hStdin DWORD ?
    priceToComp DWORD ?
.code

main PROC
    invoke SetConsoleTitle, addr sConsTitle
    invoke StdOut, addr strTask

    invoke StdOut, offset sPrompt
    invoke StdIn, offset buffer, lengthof buffer
    invoke atol, addr buffer
    mov DWORD PTR priceToComp, eax

    invoke PrintGoods, addr good_1
    invoke PrintGoods, addr good_2
    invoke PrintGoods, addr good_3

    invoke Sleep, INFINITE
    invoke ExitProcess, NULL
main ENDP

PrintGoods PROC ptrGood:PTR Good
    mov eax, priceToComp
    cmp eax, Good.Price
    jg m1
    jmp exit
    m1:
        mov ebx, ptrGood
        invoke StdOut, ebx
        invoke StdOut, addr comma

        add ebx, SIZEOF Good.Abbr
        invoke StdOut, ebx
        invoke StdOut, addr comma

        add ebx, sizeof Good.Descr
        invoke ltoa, [ebx], addr buffer
        invoke StdOut, addr buffer
        invoke StdOut, addr comma

        add ebx, sizeof Good.Price
        invoke ltoa, [ebx], addr buffer
        invoke StdOut, addr buffer
        invoke StdOut, addr clrt
    exit:

    ret
PrintGoods ENDP


END main
```

Comment: You should add the pointer just like you do for printing. E.g. `mov ebx, ptrGood; cmp eax, [ebx+Good.Price]`.

Comment: Actually masm seems to support `cmp eax, (Good PTR [ebx]).Price`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13451393/547981)